# How to read external rss file?

Tags: php, xml, symfony1

I should to display datas from a rss file from another server.

When the rss file is on my server, I can read it, but when I try to read the same file on another server, I obtain this :

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(rssfile)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed
>   to open stream: Connection timed out
>   in
>   index.php
>   on line 43
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external
>   entity
>   "rssfile"
>   in
>   index.php
>   on line 43

This is my code :

```
$actus = simplexml_load_file('rssfile');  
foreach ($actus->channel->item as $actu) 
{  

echo $actu->title;

}
```

How to fix it ?

I think the problem comes from Symfony

Comment: Just to make sure: you're trying to load a file **from another server** using the "address" `'rssfile'`?

Comment: yes, 'rssfile' is the file on this 'other' server

Comment: So, how would anyone know where and how `'rssfile'` is to be found?

Comment: "yes, 'rssfile' is the file on this 'other' server" - so, actually, in your _real_ code, you have something like `simplexml_load_file('http://some.host/a/path/foo.rss')` and `rssfile` is just something you put in there and forgot to mention?

Comment: VolherK : Yes.
But for me, the problem comes from Symfony, because I try the same code into "basic" php file, and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can then read it with something like this ...

```
private static string LoadResource(string rname)
{
    System.IO.Stream s = null;

    try
    {
        s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(rname);
        return new System.IO.StreamReader(s).ReadToEnd();
    }

    finally
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and wrong subject ;-) Maybe you meant to post an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498898/load-an-embedded-animated-cursor-from-the-resource ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error/warning message is "Connection timed out" let's take a closer look at the timeout options.
There's [default_socket_timeout](http://docs.php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.default-socket-timeout) and the [http context option `timeout`](http://docs.php.net/context.http) which might have been set via [stream_context_set_default](http://docs.php.net/function.stream-context-set-default).

Try this

```
$xmlsrc = 'http://some.host/a/path/foo.rss';
$actus = simplexml_load_file($xmlsrc);
if ( !$actus ) {
  echo "simplexml_load_file() failed.<br />\n";
  echo '$xmlsrc='; var_dump($xmlsrc); echo "<br />\n";
  echo 'default_socket_timeout=', ini_get('default_socket_timeout'), "<br />\n";
  $defaultOptions = stream_context_get_options(stream_context_get_default());
  echo 'default options='; var_dump($defaultOptions); echo "<br />\n";
  die;
}

foreach ($actus->channel->item as $actu) ...
```

in both scenarios (with/without symfony) on the same server. Do the (timeout) values differ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with VolkerK, the error comes from a bad url provided.

In addition, as you are using symfony, I advise you to go for sfFeed2Plugin that will do a lot more than the simplexml loader (validation, output methods, and even, if needed, serving).

Here's a quick usage example:

```
// define your source url
$source_url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch';

// fetch url
if($feed = sfFeedPeer::createFromWeb($source_url))
{
  // get items
  $items = $feed->getItems();

  foreach($items as $item)
  {
    // do whatever you want with each item
    echo $item->getTitle()."\n";
  }
}
```